# Black screen after login with cursor

Tags: ati, 13.04, login

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and one day ago I've just installed updates, after I turned off my computer and then when I restarted I just can see a black screen with cursor after login.

Note: I can login.

I've tried to start with unity 2d but it doesn't come with this Ubuntu version, I've installed but it wasn't added to desktop managers options. Also I've tried to reinstall my ATI Drivers from a tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1).

Note. My graphics card is an ATI 6850HD.

Please, help what can I do?

Comment: press ctrl + alt + del then after 1 sec press enter it will log you out ....then login again

Comment: I've got it. I've just downloaded a newer version of ATI Drivers nd installed it. It works for me.

How do I mark as solved this question?

Comment: You can answer your own question...

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED. I've got it. I've just downloaded a newer version of ATI Drivers nd installed it. It works for me. How do I mark as solved this question?

Comment: I think you have to wait 24 or 48 hours for that

Comment: just click on accept answer it will show you how much time left ...